# Custom Header settings don't show up in Wordpress customizer

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, header

[customizer.php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcl0M.png)

```
function custom_header_settings($wp_customize){

$wp_customize->add_section( 'header_settings' , array(
    'title'      => 'Header Settings',
    'priority'   => 30,
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'background_color' , array(
    'default'     => '#43C6E4',
    'transport'   => 'refresh',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'background_color', array(
    'label'      => 'Background Color',
    'section'    => 'header_settings',
    'settings'   => 'background_color',
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_textcolor' , array(
    'default'   => '#ffffff',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
) ); 

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_textcolor', array(
    'label'      => 'Title Color',
    'section'    => 'header_settings',
    'settings'   => 'header_textcolor'
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'description_textcolor' , array(
    'default'   => '#ffffff',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
) ); 

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'description_textcolor', array(
    'label'      => 'Description Color',
    'section'    => 'header_settings',
    'settings'   => 'description_textcolor'
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_background_image', array(
    'default'   => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/test.jpg',
));  

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_background_image', array(
'label'    => __( 'Upload Background Image', 'm1' ),
'section'  => 'header_settings',
'settings' => 'header_background_image',
) ) );

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'custom_header_settings' );
?>
```

I'm trying to get my custom header section to show up in my customize panel on Wordpress but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried re-uploading to Filezilla but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To what hook did you assign this function?

Comment: What do you mean by hook?

Comment: @SaraJ please do select the right answer once it solves your problem so that others facing the same issue can also get the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the function you need to call it: either directly in the php template or, in this case, via a hook. In your code example there is only a function's definition, so it just rests there without ever running. Also you're lacking a curly brace at the end.

Hook is quite a fitting word, because you can attach your functions to it, as if you'd hook them. And when this hook is used, it also brings the attached functions with it, because they're pinned to it. I hope this helps understanding the concept...

So just add this function to a hook after its definition, like so:

```
function custom_header_settings($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'header_settings' , array(
        'title'      => 'Header Settings',
        'priority'   => 30,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'background_color' , array(
        'default'     => '#43C6E4',
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'background_color', array(
        'label'      => 'Background Color',
        'section'    => 'header_settings',
        'settings'   => 'background_color',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'custom_header_settings' );
```

The last line adds your function `custom_header_settings` to `customize_register` hook, so it's going to get called when needed (when you go to customizer settings the `customize_register` hook is called and now it will also run your function). You can read through the detailed examples on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API).

You can also read more on filters and actions (which are, essentially, hooks) in Wordpress on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks).

**UPDATE**: turns out the file wasn't properly included in functions.php (read comments for details). Including it properly solved the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post my full code but I do have that in there at the end and it's still not working.

Comment: To which file did you add it? Also you removed the opening `<?php` from your code example, I assume it's still there? The file should be **functions.php** in your theme's folder. I'd suggest turning debugging on (`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in **wp-config.php**, more details here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Yes the opening is there, and I put it in my inc/customizer.php file in my themes folder.

Comment: in my functions.php I have 'include inc/customizer.php'

Comment: Then you are missing quotes (if that's not a typo), it should be `include 'inc/customizer.php';`. Have you checked if you get any errors after changing the debug mode? I don't see any errors in your function, everything seems to be in accordance with the documentation...

Comment: Alright. I guess you can still mark my answer as the answer, I also added an update there to clarify what was wrong.